# reset plone to access theming control panel

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I am new to theming in plone 4.3. I was experimenting and set up a rules.xml file to read an existing index.html theme that I had - it of course did not theme correctly and worst - I cannot find a way to log back into the theming control panel. The index.html contents appear on the plone page (without the css somewhow), but I want to go back and remove the rules. I tried to delete the rules.xml file, but that did not help - any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the message at the top of that page says, the theming control panel is never themed. You can get to it directly by URL, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@theming-controlpanel`. Then disable your theme on the 'Advanced settings' tab.

Alternatively you can disable Diazo for a page by appending `diazo.off=1` in the query string, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/Plone/front-page?diazo.off=1`

Comment: When I try to access @@theming-control panel, it gives me back [link](http://localhost:8080/learnandapply/acl_users/credentials_cookie_auth/require_login?came_from=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/learnandapply/%40%40theming-controlpanel) and the second option does not do anything and defaults back to the above link. I cleared by browser cache and cookies just in case, but that did not help

Comment: Use the ?diazo.off option or access via http://127.0.0.1:8080 instead of http://localhost:8080. The link you are seeing is because you are being sent to a login page.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @optilude . It worked. Is the way to turn it on ?diazo.on=1?